# Problems with column array (PHPExcel)

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

Sorry, I searched but didn't find any solution to my problem.
I created an array  that I want to export with PHPExcel, in one column (tableauBK):

```
if ($tableauBK[$k]<>"" && $tableauQ[$k]<>"")
    {
$tableauBL[$k]=$tableauBK[$k]*$tableauQ[$k];
    }
```

I can read the array without problems:

```
foreach ($tableauBL as $subtab)
{

    echo $subtab;
}
```

But I can't place the array in a column of my Excel file. I tried to make this code:

```
for ($row = 5; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) 
{
foreach ($tableauBL as $subtab)
{

    ->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $subtab)
}
```

But it doesn't work... 
I hope, you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Krokodike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a case of PHP array handling

```
$row = 5;
foreach ($tableauBL as $subtab)
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row++, $subtab);
}
```

or even simply

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(array($tableauBL), null, 'A5');
```